# Change the style of transition from view to view

Tags: ios, uiview, uimodaltransitionstyle

i currently use that method to transition between view1 to view2:

```
-(IBAction)goToView2{
    view2.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];
}
```

This make the view2 cover view1 vertically, what i want is to cover it horizontaly as it down in the Navigation based application template, is there any possibility to do so, i use a View based application, thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do it out of the box using the modal view cover.
One way of simulating this is to create the second view off screen using a standard add subview command in a rect beyond the screen bounds and then do a uiview animation to bring the new view in and the old view out. Let me know if you need more help.